# Wordpress contact form 7 pass values from a form to contact form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, contacts, contact-form-7

so i have a quote generator that creates a quote depending on specific selected options. once the user is happy, they click on 'book' to send the details to an email address.

basically...I have a select option drop down in a form. the user selects an option from the drop down.

```
<label for="timehours">Hour<br><select name="time" id="timehours">
```

the user then, after filling some other bits on the form, and once they are happy, selects a submit button or a link and a contact form pops up (using fancy box & contact form 7)
what i would like to do is grab the selected option plus other fields and put in the contact form as part of the message or as a separate field if easier

thanks

Comment: I don't think your question is very well stated, as I had a tough time understand what your actually trying to accomplish. Are you trying to accomplish "calculated form fields"? Is there a reason you are trying to do this with Contact Form 7 instead of a more powerful engine like Gravity Forms (gravity forms has calculated form fields).

Comment: This might be helpful https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/

Answer (score 0):

This would require you to modify CF7 which there is little point in doing, as any updates will wipe your changes. If you use Wordpress a lot I would strongly recommend learning how to build your own form(s) as part of a simple plugin. Then you don't have to rely on hacking CF7 to make it accept your custom data.